# Initialize C++ object array within the Constructor Initializer List

Tags: c++, arm, keil, armcc

I am trying to initialize an array of objects. This seems to fail in Keil, using the **armcc** compiler, using the --cpp11 flag.

The following is my class `Wheel` which would be used later in the Vehicle class.

```
class Wheel
{
public:
    Wheel(const uint8_t diameter);
private:
    uint8_t m_diameter;
};
```

The `Vehicle` class employs an array of Wheel, and these are initialized within the constructor. I would like to ideally initialize it like this:

```
class Vehicle
{
public:
    Vehicle();

private:
    Wheel wheels[3];
};

//in Wheel.cpp
// Constructor 
Vehicle::Vehicle()
    : wheels{Wheel(3),Wheel(4),Wheel(5)} 
{}
```

The other option would be to initialize everything within the constructor body, like this:

```
Vehicle::Vehicle(){
wheel[0] = Wheel(3);
wheel[1] = Wheel(4);
wheel[2] = Wheel(5);}
```

The compiler [documentation](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armcc/armcc_chr1407404265784.htm) mentions:

> ARM Compiler supports initializer lists and uniform initialization, but the standard library does not provide an implementation of `std::initializer_list`. With a user-supplied implementation of `std::initializer_list` initializer lists and uniform initialization can be used.

How can I define an initializer list for my usecase?

Comment: The second option is no viable, as `wheels` is first initialized with 3 "empty" wheels, and `Wheel` doesn't have default constructor.

Comment: You could use `std::array<Wheel, 3> wheels;` instead of `Wheel wheels[3];`

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, thats right. That's the reason I want to avoid it.

Comment: That said, OP, are you getting an actual error?  `wheels{Wheel(3),Wheel(4),Wheel(5)}` should not be using a `std::initializer_list`.

Comment: @ThomasSablik, unfortunately, the standard lib of armcc does not support `std::array`.

Comment: @NathanOliver, Keil doesn't throw an error during compilation. I see it compilers the file and then during linking, I see an error saying the object file for the corresponding .cpp file is missing.

Comment: @NathanOliver: When I run the build process with CMake, I see the following error: `fatal error U1077: 'C:\Keil_v5\ARM\ARMCC\bin\armcc.exe' : return code '0xc0000005'`, on compiling Class source file.